# Array within an array?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to call up an element from an array within an array in Python. For example:

```
array = [[a1,a2,a3,a4], [b1,b2,b3,b4], [c1,c2,c3,c4]]
```

The question is, how would I print just the value b1?

Comment: They are called lists in Python.

Comment: What you have is a list, not an array. Just treat it like you would any other list. You want the second sublist's first element, so just write `array[1][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access `b1`, do this:

```
print array[1][0]
```

See an example:

```
>>> array=[['a1','a2','a3','a4'],['b1','b2','b3','b4'],['c1','c2','c3','c4']]
>>> array[1]
['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']
>>> array[1][0]
'b1'
>>>
```

Basically, you are indexing `array` at position 1 (which returns the b list), and then indexing *that* list at position 0 (which returns `b1`).

Comment: Why the downvote?  Please leave a reason so I can explain/improve my post.  IMO, downvoting with no reason is a waste of the privilege.

Comment: Yours was downvoted as well? It appears the downvote is gone now though (mine is still there).

Comment: Yes.  I think someone is just messing with us instead of taking this site seriously.

Comment: People are free to vote as they see fit; I just would appreciate feedback if they do. Especially when downvoting multiple answers that to my eyes are perfectly correct.

Answer (score 2):

By applying indexing on the nested list:

```
lst = [
    ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
    ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'], 
    ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
]
b1 = lst[1][0]
```

The first index returns the *object* at that position; that object happens to be a list as well, so you can immediately apply another index to that result.

This extends to dictionaries and attributes as well. You can use list methods on those same nested lists:

```
lst[1].count('b1')
```

for example.

If it helps understanding, imagine assigning the result of the first indexing operation to a temporary variable:

```
tmp = lst[1]
b1 = tmp[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply access the array element from an array element, something like this:

```
array[1][0]
```